# how do I write a php code that substract some amount with the current amount each day when logging in?

Tags: php

```
<?php
        global $database;

        $get_amount = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE account_type='member'";
        $run_amount = mysqli_query($database,$get_amount);
        $row        = mysqli_fetch_array($run_amount);

        $user_amount    = $row['amount'];
        $user_daily_cut = round($user_amount / 365,2);
        $total_amount   = round($user_amount - $user_daily_cut,2);

        if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
        {
            header("Location: index.php");
            die();
        }
        else    
        {
            $update_rent = "UPDATE users SET amount='$total_amount' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
            $rent_update = mysqli_query($database,$update_rent);


            echo "Rs : $total_amount left"; 
        }       
?>
```

Can anyone please correct my logic? I need that amount to be deducted everyday when i log in! My code is somehow not correct. please help me make this logic anyone. thanks..

Comment: `$total_amount` is not related to the logged in `user`. I also don't see `$user_id` being set, and you can do this all in mysql (it has math functionality).

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the global user_id, bdw which math function is suitable for this?

Comment: Maybe something like `UPDATE users SET amount= (amount / 365) - amount where userid = ? and account_type='member'` Then I don't think you need that select either.

Comment: i think this logic is somehow related to session and cookies? im just a noob with cookies

Comment: Oh? Well then the above are other logic notes for you. For `$_SESSION['email']` to be accessible you need to start the session, did you do that?

Comment: yup session_start() has been done at the top, which i thought was not required to show here lol

Comment: Yes, minimal is best, but I don't know whats happening with the code execution yet. Can you describe what happens currently when you process this?

Comment: when this code is executed, this shows an amount which is same as the database amount but the amount does not deducts. i want the amount to deduct the very next day. thats what im trying to do? please guide me sir

Comment: So you get `Rs : $total_amount left` displayed correctly, but the DB doesnt update? What is `var_dump($rent_update);`?

Comment: and how do we do it when it comes to updating the amount automatically eveyday? for loop??